# How to use limits of $f'(x)$ to show that f is differentiable at a given $x_0$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to prove the following statement (assuming that it is true):

> Given that a function $f:\mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$
> satisfies the following:
>
> - Defined in a $\delta$ neighborhood of $0$
> - Differentiable in the deleted $\delta$-neighborhood of $0$, $ \mathit{N}^*_\delta=(-\delta,0) \cup (0,\delta)$
> - $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}  f'(x) = 1$
>
> Then
>
> $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=1$

I understand that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) = 1$ implies that, either

- $f'$ is continuous at $x=0$ and then $f'$ exists at $x=1$ and and $f'(0)=1$,
  or
- $f'$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=0$

I am trying to prove that the second option is not possible.

Any ideas or sugestions would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f'$ is continuous at $x=0$? Anyway, what about $f(x) =\sqrt[3]{x^5}+x, x \ne 0, f(x)=1, x=0$?

Comment: Thank you corrected

Comment: What does "deleted $\delta$-neighborhood" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if $f(x)$  is defined by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x \quad &\text{if $x <0$}\\
1+x \quad & \text{if $x>0$}\\
1 \quad &\text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$$

?

Answer (score 0):

The assumptions imply that  $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ exists. Indeed, since $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=1$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $|f'(x)|<2$ for $|x|<\delta.$ By the intermediate value theorem we get  that for $0|x|,|y|<\delta$ there holds
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(\xi)|\,|x-y|\le 2|x-y|$$ The inequality implies the existence of the limit at $0.$ Hence $f$ has the removable singularity at $0.$ We may redefine the value at $0,$ so that $f$ becomes continuous at $0.$
After doing this,  by the mean value theorem, we get $${f(x)-f(0)\over x}=f'(\xi)\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow }1$$ Therefore $f'(0)=1,$ hence $f'$ is continuous at $0.$

Obviously the conclusion does not hold if we do not redefine the function $f$ at $0.$